# I wrote entity like this and i got data which deleted = 'false'. How i should get deleted='true'

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I wrote entity like this and i got data which deleted = 'false'. How i should get deleted='true'.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hr_personal", indexes = {@Index(columnList = "id")})
@SQLDelete(sql = " update hr_personal set deleted = 'true' where id = ?")
@Where(clause = "deleted = 'false'")
public class HrPersonalEntity extends AbstractAuditingEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    String firstname;

    @Column(name = "deleted")
    private boolean deleted = false;
}
```

Comment: `@Where(clause = "deleted = 'ture'")` but both will not together. To get both you can remove this where clause and do query in repository

Comment: how can get deleted='false'

Comment: Map another entity, like HistoricHrPersonalEntity, and annotate it with `@Where(clause = "deleted = 'true'")`, you should also make it `@Immutable`

Comment: In my opinion this way incorect

Comment: You have 2 WHERE clauses, one in the query itself and one separate.